# How can I implement N choose K, allowing repetition of elements and make low priority for outputs with repetitive elements?

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm

I need an algorithm to return all combination of K elements from n element, except that the object can be repeated. For example consider the following objects: A, B, C
Then the relation between input and output is as below(Input_Of_Algorithm -> output):

```
0 -> A
1 -> B
2 -> C
3 -> A,B
4 -> A,C
5 -> B,C
6 -> A,A
7 -> B,B
8 -> C,C
9 -> A,B,C
10-> A,A,B
11-> A,A,C
12-> A,B,B
13-> A,C,C
14-> B,B,C
15-> B,C,C
16-> A,A,A
17-> B,B,B
18-> C,C,C
19-> A,A,B,C
20-> A,B,B,C
21-> A,B,C,C
.
.
.
and so on ...
```

The point is that the order inside 0..2, 3..5, 6..8 and similar clusters is not important. The important part of algorithm is that the clusters with repeated objects have less priority. It means that AAA,BBB,CCC always come after AAB,AAC,ABB,ACC,BBC,BCC . Also AAB,AAC,ABB,ACC,BBC,BCC always come after ABC.
Is there any idea that how can I implement this algorithm?

Comment: Complexity restrictions?

Comment: Nope! Neither  complexity, nor memory restrictions.

Comment: How do A,A,A,A,B,B and A,A,A,B,B,B get ordered?

Comment: AAABBB comes before AAAABB.

Comment: What about AABBBB and AAABBBB? AAABC and AABBC?

Comment: AABBBB have 6 elements, so it should be prior to AAABBBB which have 7 elements.

Comment: I meant AAABBB obviously. What about my other question?

Comment: Repetition is right the inverse rank, so AABBC is prior to AAABC; cause the first one has maximum 2 repetition for each element, but the second one has maximum 3 repetition for each element.

Comment: AAABBB is prior to AABBBB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution involves pasting together a couple of combinatorial enumeration algorithms. It is reasonably efficient. In Python 3:

```
def integer_partitions(length, total, bound=None, prefix=()):
  if length > 0:
    if bound is None or bound > total:
      bound = total
    for part in range((total - 1 + length) // length, bound + 1):
      yield from integer_partitions(length - 1, total - part,
                                    part, prefix + (part,))
  else:
    yield prefix
```

The inner step looks like this.

```
def strings_from_partitions(letters, partition, prefix=''):
  if letters:
    for part in sorted(set(partition), reverse=True):  # toss duplicates
      residual = list(partition)
      residual.remove(part)
      yield from strings_from_partitions(letters[1:], residual,
                                         prefix + letters[0] * part)
  else:
    yield prefix
```

Putting it all together.

```
def strings(letters):
  total = 1
  while True:
    for partition in integer_partitions(len(letters), total):
      yield from strings_from_partitions(letters, partition)
    total += 1
```

Comment: Thx for answering, but I'm not familiar with python. Is it translatable to C# ? or any additional functionality needed?

Comment: @MorTezaDM There's definitely a translation to C#. It will be more verbose. I can't do it.